# Constraining generics in Typescript JSDoc

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I'm using the JSDoc form of TypeScript and am trying to use a generic that extends an object. My editor is giving me a TypeScript error for the `index.js` code declaring the parameter of type`MyInterface<T>`, saying `Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint '{ a: number; }'.`

How do I specify that I accept a generic parameter that constrains an object in JSDoc TypeScript?

```
// index.d.ts
declare interface MyInterface<T extends {a: number}> {
  b: string;
}


// index.js
/**
 * @template T
 * @param {MyInterface<T>} impl
 */
function doStuff(impl) {
  console.log(impl);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
/**
 * @template {{a: number}} T
 * @param {MyInterface<T>} impl
 */
```

`@template` constraints were implemented in [pull request 24600](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24600)